# Null error in C

Tags: c

I am new to the C language and I don't quite understand what is going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am able to take input, but it is lost in memory somewhere and not assigned nor printed. It prints nothing, but (null)(null)(null) and that's all.

```
   int setPersonalInfo(void)
{
    char first, last, sex;
    printf ("Enter your first name: ");
    scanf ("%s", &first);

    printf ("Enter your last name: ");
    scanf ("%s", &last);

    printf ("Enter your gender (M or F): ");
    scanf ("%s", &sex);
};


int printInfo()
{
    char first, last, sex;
    int month, day, year;
    printf("%s\n%s%s%s\n", sex, first, " ", last);

    printf("%u%s%u%s%u\n", month, "/", day,"/", year);    
};
```

Comment: `first` and friends are *single character* variables. You are trying to stuff them with strings.

Comment: You're reading user input into local variables within the `setPersonalInfo` and `setAgeInfo` functions, but you're not passing that data out of the function. When the function returns, those variables go out of scope and are lost forever.

Comment: So what youre saying Mike Holt is that I need to remove the declaration in the functions? Because when I do that i get many errors.

Comment: Do you know about *local variables*?

Comment: No, we literally just started learning C about two weeks ago.

Comment: Is this a homework exercise? If you haven't covered variables yet, this might explain the errors. What is the exact phrasing of the assignment?

Comment: Two major misunderstandings. First, "char" type is a single character, and you're trying to read a whole string into it. Second, the variables like "first", "last", "sex" are local to the function they are declared in, so even if you successfully read and set them from input, they disappear when the function returns, and the variables with the same name in printInfo() are new variables local to that function which have never been set.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here

```
int setPersonalInfo(void)
{
    char first, last, sex;
    printf ("Enter your first name: ");
    scanf ("%s", &first);

    printf ("Enter your last name: ");
    scanf ("%s", &last);

    printf ("Enter your gender (M or F): ");
    scanf ("%s", &sex);
};
```

is wrong. `first`, `last` and `sex` are single character variables, the can hold
a single charcater only.

A string in C is a sequence of characters that ends with the `'\0'`-terminating
byte. `scanf` expects a pointer to an array of `char`s where the sequence of
charatcers can be stored. `&first` gives you only a pointer to a `char`, but
it's not a pointer to an array of `char`s, it can hold only one value. A string
of length `n` needs at least `n+1` spaces.

Correct version:

```
int setPersonalInfo(void)
{
    char first[20], last[20], sex[20];
    printf ("Enter your first name: ");
    scanf ("%19s", first);

    printf ("Enter your last name: ");
    scanf ("%19s", last);

    printf ("Enter your gender (M or F): ");
    scanf ("%19s", sex);
};
```

Next problem:

```
int printInfo()
{
    char first, last, sex;
    int month, day, year;
    printf("%s\n%s%s%s\n", sex, first, " ", last);

    printf("%u%s%u%s%u\n", month, "/", day,"/", year);    
};
```

Here you two problems:

1. The variables are uninitialized
2. You have a similar problem as above.

`first`, `last`, `sex` are single charatcer variables. `printf` expects with `%s` a pointer to
a string, you are passing the uninitialized value of a `char` as a pointer. This
is undefined behaviour and the text printed on screen is meaningless.

But the biggest issue here is that the functions read values and store them in
their local variables. Once the functions ends, the local variables cease to
exit and the values are lost. The function should return those values or you
need to pass pointers to the functions, so that the functions can use the
pointers to store the values: like this:

```
void foo(int *val)
{
    *val = 15;
}

void bar(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    foo(&x);

    // now x is 15
}
```